# error logging in c - linux environment

Tags: c, linux, logging, error-logging

I have been reading about how to keep error/warning logs of a C program on Linux environment. Is it better to write the `errno` to a file as it is done [here](http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/c/c1.htm) or is it better to use `syslog` or `setlogmask` system calls or another method? I would appreciate an answer with an example code.

Comment: Notice that `syslog` is *not* a system call (which are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using syslog for logging errors as its more standard way of logging.

you can look at the example implemenation here (bio3d.colorado.edu/tor/sadocs/misc/syslog.html)

Also unix network programming book by richard stevens also contains good explanation of using syslog

Answer (score 2):

The above link no longer works - try this one here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog-Example.html#Syslog-Example

....which contains the following example:

```
#include <syslog.h>

setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));

openlog ("exampleprog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Program started by User %d", getuid ());
syslog (LOG_INFO, "A tree falls in a forest");
closelog ();
```